# I want to use t method for href of a tag and custom data attribute instead of nuxt-link when using Nuxt.js + i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Dynamic multilingual sites from the backend to the replacement of large sites
I changed the language, but this time I am trying for the first time to do it at the front desk (Nuxt.js + i18n).

```
<a href="https://gooogle/en.com" data-link="fugafuga">
```

Without using nuxt-link

```
<template>
  <a href="https://gooogle/｛｛t('locale')｝｝.com" data-link="｛｛t('hogehoge')｝｝" >
</template>
```

Is it possible to divert and use a tag as it is?
(In the above writing method, an error occurred and it was useless, so please teach me a workaround)
I18n t method wrapped in quotes in  inside tag quote
How do I write it?

Such a shape is desirable because the scale is too large
We apologize for the inconvenience, but we would appreciate it if you could teach us.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested fix:

```
<template>
  <a :href="`https://google/${t('locale')}.com`" :data-link="t('hogehoge')"></a>
</template>
```

You can read more about data binding with Vue/Nuxt here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax